# Qual a diferença entre .h e .hpp e quando usar (C++)

Tags: c++, header

Arquivos .h são usados no C/C++ como arquivos de cabeçalho onde todos o conteúdo deles é passado automaticamente para um outro arquivo .cpp e de sua escolha usando o comando:

```
#include <arquivo.h>
```

Mas recentemente eu vi um código onde os header files estavam como .hpp em vez de .h , testei mudar alguns códigos aqui no meu computador renomeando os arquivos de cabeçalho e não ouve nenhuma diferença aparente. Então qual a diferença entre .h e .hpp ? Quando usar um e quando usar outro ?

Comment: Pela resposta da outra pergunta, a unica diferença entre .h e .hpp é que  .hpp só pode ser usado em C++ ? Só isso ?

Comment: sim. Inclusive, quando se almeja que a biblioteca seja usada no C e no C++, ela deve ser `.h` e de grosso modo não pode usar as coisas do C++ sem proteger com `ifdefs`